# Membership reminders sending each time scheduled job runs after 4.6.2 upgrade

Tags: civimember, 4.6.2, scheduled-reminders

We upgraded to 4.6.2 in our test environment and since then our membership renewal reminders are sending emails each time the cron job runs. The reminder is scheduled to send 2 days before membership expiration with no repeats. Our cron job runs every 30 minutes, so the reminder is sent every 30 minutes for the entire 24 hour period. Is there something I need to reset? This only happens with reminders that were set up prior to our 4.6.2 upgrade. All new reminders work properly.

This does seem really similar to issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16514. Could use some help looking into it. I can duplicate the issue.

Comment: Hi Jane - we got caught out with something a bit like this - everyone got sent Reminders, rather than just the 'targets', and it was prior to 4.6 -  we had set the 'limited to' to be 'additional' (or whatever the corollary is), and having left the next field blank the query incorrectly assumed we meant 'heh let's send it to everyone' (gahh)
Only mentioning this in case you can spot any other settings on your Scheduled Reminder that might ring alarm bells.
Other option would be to construct a new Reminder from scratch and see if that behaves? and if so what differences you can spot?

Comment: This sounds very similar to this reported bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16514.  Jane, could you read that over and see if it sounds like the same thing?  If so, it sounds like you have valuable additional information that could be crucial to troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Jon G - Yes, I think it is the same issue. What information can I provide to help? I can look at whatever you might need, just still getting familiar with CiviCRM so might not be able to debug on my own.

Comment: I commented on the issue pointing to this - sounds like the core team couldn't replicate the problem, but now will test upgrading to see if they can replicate the problem.  Meanwhile - do you know how to output SQL?  Try creating a scheduled reminder identical to a broken reminder, then run the SQL statement `select * from civicrm_action_schedule`.  See if there's a difference between the two reminder records that you can identify?

Comment: I took a look at the civicrm_action_schedule and there is nothing different from the scheduled reminders. All columns (except the unique id, name and message) are identical. I also took a look at the civicrm_action_log and nothing stands out there. I can see an entry for each individual email sent. The email definitely should not be repeating every time the Scheduled Jobs task is run, but it is.

Comment: @Jane - Have you seen the latest request for info on the ticket? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16514

Comment: We're still seeing this problem. I saw the request for information on that ticket - yes, it seems similar although for events. I will post there as well, but we really could use some help with this. Once the email has been sent once at the correct time, it begins to send every time the cron job runs. There doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary with the logs or the scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a recent JIRA ticket [18326](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18236)

- Scheduled reminder set to run one week before membership end date
- Reminder runs once, then membership end date is changed
- When the next date comes around it correctly sends a reminder but it incorrectly sends a reminder every cron until the next date has ended